# Creating a form

Tags: 6, forms

I am new to Drupal 6. I have been playing around with the settings and have been able to create a static website.

What I can't seem to figure out is how I create a form with some input fields and a submit button.  When the submit button is clicked, the form data should be saved into a database table.

This is straight forward stuff using raw PHP/MySQL, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Drupal.

Answer (score 6):

To write a module that displays a form, there is a link called "Form generation" on http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/6, which then links to [the quickstart guide](http://drupal.org/node/751826).

As an alternative, have a look at the http://drupal.org/project/webform project, which allows you to create forms through the User Interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd just like to collect data from your users, such as a contact form or a feedback form, or even a simple survey, you can check out the [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module which will allow you to collect the data, review it later, download it as a CSV, and, optionally, send you an email every time someone fills it in.

Comment: Oops, sorry Berdir, I only just saw that you already mentioned this in the second part of your answer.